# Kickstarter embedded videos not working on mobile

Tags: video, mobile, embedding

I am embedding kickstarter videos on my site -- they work fine in all desktop browsers, but do not appear to work in any of the mobile devices I've tested (galaxy S4, nexus tablet, iphone, ipad).

I'm using Kickstarter's iframe embedding, looks like this:

```
<iframe width='480' 
        height='360' 
        src='http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/rambod-geometrical/pocket-tripod-360-wallet-sized-iphone-stand/widget/video.html' 
        frameborder='0'> 
</iframe>
```

Any ideas why it would work fine in all desktop browsers but not any mobile ones?  I'd also note that the videos play fine on Kickstarter's own website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration with Kickstarter's own video player, I changed approach to use videojs:

http://www.videojs.com/

It seems to work well in all browsers and formats; I just had to grab the source urls from the original embed (.mp4 and .webm) along with a "poster" image to use in the embed code for videojs.  Then it does the rest.